# Setting default path in Unix

Tags: unix, fedora, path, environment-variables

I just installed **[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)** on my Fedora12 machine.

```
$ valgrind                       // 1
$ valgrind: Command not found.   //error
$ /usr/local/bin/valgrind        // 2 works fine
```

My `$PATH` has `/usr/local/bin` in it.

**Is there something else that I need to do to make 1 work?**

Comment: Just to check, echo $PATH?

Comment: What's wrong with Fedora's valgrind package?

Comment: @fideli: /usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/X11R6/bin

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: my Fedora did not have one.

Comment: Well then you don't have Fedora, because Fedora has one.

Comment: As an additional wacky check, do *which valgrind* and make sure that it's not trying to execute one in another directory.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: :) previously, when I typed `valgrind`, it said `Command not found`.  Also, `cat /etc/fedora-release` says `Fedora release 12 (Constantine)`

Comment: @satanicpuppy: `which valgrind` --> `/usr/local/bin/valgrind`

Comment: If you're using Bash, do `type -a valgrind`. This will show whether an alias or a function is superseding the one(s) found in the path. It will also show if it appears at more than one point in the path.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: not aliased. But from aliasing, I tried one thing and it works. i have set `valgrind` as an alias to `/usr/local/bin/valgrind` :)

Comment: Did you bother typing `yum install valgrind`?

Comment: Try `echo "'$PATH'"|cat -v` or `echo "'$PATH'"|hexdump -C` to see if there are any odd characters in your path. Also, do other executables in `/usr/local/bin` work properly? And is there anything about `valgrind` itself that requires a fully specified path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after logging out and re-logging in the system.

Answer (score 0):

it changes depending on your shell.  In tcsh, for instance, do:

```
set path = ($path /usr/local/bin)
```